# html element: newline after but do not expand

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a html/css solution to obtain following behavior for some html element:

- It must force a new-line after it, that is, no other element can be in the same line after it. Similar to a `div` or `display: block`.
- Its size must be the one of his content, not expand to all line. Similar to a `span` or `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.
- We can choice the kind of element (`div`, `span`, ...) but it must be a single one, no possible to use, by example, a `span` followed of a `br`.

In the following example there are several tries to obtain this behavior, all them unsuccessful.:

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
}

#yellow {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#red {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#blue {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="yellow">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="red">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The yellow div expands over all line width, exceeding the 50px of its content. The red one ( a div with display inline-block) has the correct size, but doesn't forces next div (the blue one) to appear in next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `max-width: fit-content`? Not supported on IE or Edge.

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
}

#yellow {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-width: -webkit-fit-content;
  max-width: -moz-fit-content;
  max-width: fit-content;
}

#red {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#blue {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="yellow">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="red">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to do the expected behavior. Never listen about this value for max-width, it doesn't appears at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp . Please, any way to know these possible values ?

Comment: this value is not yet supported by all the browsers, `IE` and `Edge` do not support it. See [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content) for `fit-content`.

Comment: w3schools is a pretty terrible resource for the actual documentation (good for examples, though). Use Mozilla's: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi I think it's better if you add a reference for browser support of the `fit-content` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `display: table` to `#yellow` as `display: table` acts as an `inline-block` element by being as wide as its content, but also acts as a `block` element by adding a line break before and after the element.

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
}

#yellow {
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  border-collapse: separate; /** added to allow padding to apply if used **/
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#red {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#blue {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="yellow">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="red">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Personally, I don't recommend using table based designs as they're not responsive, but due to your requirements I use so you don't have to use any other element and also **it's supported by all the major browsers**.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps. Small change to the original body `width` and making the display for Yellow to be `inline-block` will make it work.

```css
body {
  width: 50px;
}

#yellow {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#red {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#blue {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="yellow">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="red">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your collaboration. Unfortunately this solution is not applicable, in the real case, because html and body element are 100% of screen width and the elements are inside a div inside a div inside a flex inside ... .